# Submit form only if at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, submit

i'm triyng to validate a form.
In this form you've to choose at least one element by checkboxes, and I can't be sure about their quantity (it depends by elements number).
I need to enable the submit input if one or more checkboxes are checked, and disable it if there aren't any checkbox checked, how can I do?
Here's my code:

```
<form id="booking">
<input type="checkbox" name="room1" class="roomselect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="room2" class="roomselect"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="room3" class="roomselect"/>
<input type="submit" value="Request" id="subm" />
</form>
```

Comment: Add a submit handler check `if($('.roomselect').is(':checked'))` if false prevent form submission

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //form submit handler
    $('#booking').submit(function (e) {
        //check atleat 1 checkbox is checked
        if (!$('.roomselect').is(':checked')) {
            //prevent the default form submit if it is not checked
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:checked` selector along with `.length` to find checked checkbox count:

```
var len = $(".roomselect:checked").length;
if(len>0){
    //more than one checkbox is checked
 }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T7Bd2/)**

Answer (score 2):

The [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector will Match all elements that are checked or selected.

You could try this

```
$("#subm").click(function(e){
        if($(".roomselect:checked").length == 0){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use "button" instead of "submit".

please follow this

HTML->

```
<form id="booking" action="https://www.google.co.in/search">
      <input type="checkbox" value="facebook" name="q"/>
       <input type="checkbox" value="gmail" name="q"/>
       <input type="checkbox" value="stackoverflow" name="q"/>
<input type="button" value="Request" id="submit" />
```

$(function(){

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){

    var number_of_checked_checkbox= $("input[name=q]:checked").length;
    if(number_of_checked_checkbox==0){
        alert("select any one");
    }else{
        $("#booking").submit();
    }

         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla *JavaScript* equivalent of the *jQuery* way, using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
if (document.querySelector('.roomselect:checked')) {
    // somethings checked
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3UCBe/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be with javascript, fortunately someone's already done all the work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378250/check-atleast-one-checkbox-is-checked-on-form-submission) (with jQuery). All you'd need to do to adapt that example is to change #form_check to #booking.

Essentially what that example is doing is forcing itself before the submit action when it sees one is being tried for the form then it's searching inside the form element for any checkbox elements with a checked state and if it can't find any is sending a preventdefault to stop whatever the client/browser's default response to a submit action request would be or otherwise just sending as normal.

Also regarding the other answers, using === is more secure and returning false gives you some redundancy. [Here's](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) some discussion on what the return false adds.

Additionally don't use click() for this as you potentially run into use cases where you're technically submitting the form but aren't actually clicking it, like say when you hit enter

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var checked = false;
$(function(){
    $('#subm').click(function(e){
        checkall();
        if(!checked){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $('.roomselect').change(function(e){
        checkall();
    });
    checkall();
});
function checkall()
{
    checked = $('.roomselect:checked').length > 0;
    $('#subm').prop('disabled',!checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form_id").submit(function(e) {        
    var totalChecked = $('#div_id:input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;        
    if(totalChecked < 1)
    {            
        alert('Please select at least one checkbox before submit');
        return false;
    }  

});
```